# Can't find catalina.out in OS X 10.11.3 inside apache-tomcat-8.0.33

Tags: macos, tomcat, tomcat8

I've just installed apache-tomcat-8.0.33 , I am deploying an application that has errors but I can't see catalina.out inside
**/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/logs**

I only find this file **localhost_access_log.2016-04-19.txt** with this content:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:10:31 +0200] "GET /manager/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:10:32 +0200] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 401 2473
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - admin [19/Apr/2016:20:10:33 +0200] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 200 17910
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:10:33 +0200] "GET /manager/images/asf-logo.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 7279
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:10:33 +0200] "GET /manager/images/tomcat.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 2066
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:10:33 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - admin [19/Apr/2016:20:11:07 +0200] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 200 16678
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - admin [19/Apr/2016:20:11:07 +0200] "GET /manager/images/asf-logo.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - admin [19/Apr/2016:20:11:07 +0200] "GET /manager/images/tomcat.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:11:07 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - admin [19/Apr/2016:20:11:10 +0200] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 200 16678
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - admin [19/Apr/2016:20:11:10 +0200] "GET /manager/images/tomcat.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - admin [19/Apr/2016:20:11:10 +0200] "GET /manager/images/asf-logo.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:11:10 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - admin [19/Apr/2016:20:11:23 +0200] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 200 16678
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - admin [19/Apr/2016:20:11:23 +0200] "GET /manager/images/tomcat.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - admin [19/Apr/2016:20:11:23 +0200] "GET /manager/images/asf-logo.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:11:23 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:11:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11250
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:11:29 +0200] "GET /tomcat.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5576
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:11:29 +0200] "GET /tomcat.png HTTP/1.1" 200 5103
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:11:29 +0200] "GET /bg-nav.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1401
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:11:29 +0200] "GET /bg-upper.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3103
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:11:29 +0200] "GET /asf-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 17811
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:11:29 +0200] "GET /bg-button.png HTTP/1.1" 200 713
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:11:29 +0200] "GET /bg-middle.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1918
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - admin [19/Apr/2016:20:12:51 +0200] "POST /manager/html/upload?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=087B57A87D6F7602AA424197072B81EB HTTP/1.1" 200 17949
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:16:30 +0200] "GET /ideefe-iot-web/api/login HTTP/1.1" 404 1052
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:16:30 +0200] "GET /ideefe-iot-web/api/login HTTP/1.1" 404 1052
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:16:30 +0200] "GET /ideefe-iot-web/api/application HTTP/1.1" 404 1064
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:16:30 +0200] "POST /ideefe-iot-web/api/device HTTP/1.1" 404 1054
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:16:30 +0200] "POST /ideefe-iot-web/api/device HTTP/1.1" 404 1054
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:16:30 +0200] "POST /ideefe-iot-web/api/device HTTP/1.1" 404 1054
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:16:30 +0200] "POST /ideefe-iot-web/api/login HTTP/1.1" 404 1052
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:16:30 +0200] "POST /ideefe-iot-web/api/sigfoxCallback HTTP/1.1" 404 1070
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - admin [19/Apr/2016:20:27:19 +0200] "POST /manager/html/upload?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=087B57A87D6F7602AA424197072B81EB HTTP/1.1" 403 3195
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:27:19 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:27:22 +0200] "GET /manager/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - admin [19/Apr/2016:20:27:23 +0200] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 200 17949
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - admin [19/Apr/2016:20:27:25 +0200] "POST /manager/html/undeploy?path=/ideefe%2Diot%2Dweb%2D1%2E1%2E0&org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=B1046CB8EA35C96D335BAAD0D8CD3EF0 HTTP/1.1" 200 16752
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - admin [19/Apr/2016:20:27:33 +0200] "POST /manager/html/upload?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=75AFADA2F0CAD99F17D46E3370FCF5BD HTTP/1.1" 200 17949
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:35:13 +0200] "GET /examples/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1126
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:35:16 +0200] "GET /examples/servlets HTTP/1.1" 302 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:35:16 +0200] "GET /examples/servlets/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6645
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:35:16 +0200] "GET /examples/servlets/images/execute.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 1242
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:35:16 +0200] "GET /examples/servlets/images/return.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 1231
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Apr/2016:20:35:16 +0200] "GET /examples/servlets/images/code.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 292
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have not configured the path for the CATALINA_HOME. 
Before starting you need to show the program where your CATALINA is suing environment variable